# Selenium WebDriver C# - Unable to redirect to a secured (HTTPS) URL / driver.Url or driver.Navigate().GoToUrl does NOT work in HTTPS?

Tags: c#, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

Good day! I have been using Selenium WebDriver for a few months now, and everything works awesomely fine.

However, I have been stuck with this strange problem for weeks (or maybe a month) already.

**THE PROBLEM**
We have two environments for our website, one uses a security certificate (HTTPS) while the other does not have one (HTTP). When running my Selenium scripts (written in C#) in the HTTP site, the tests worked perfectly well and executed very smoothly.
However, when I try to run the same test(s) on the HTTPS site, the tests seems to have problems in redirecting to my desired pages. Most particularly, the driver.Url does not redirect properly to the correct page.

**THE SCRIPT/CODE:**
Basically, what our tests does are as follows:

1. Go to Login page using driver.Url or driver.Navigate().GoToUrl.
   Works well for both HTTPS and HTTP.
2. After successful login, there a
   page called "Select Database" which we trigger a button. Works well
   for both HTTP and HTTPS.
3. After selecting a database, we will be
   redirected to a landing/home page. Works well for both HTTP and
   HTTPS.
4. Once we already are in the landing/home page, we then fire a
   driver.Url or driver.Navigate().GoToUrl to redirect to a desired
   page. E.g. Contact page. When executing using the HTTP site, it
   worked perfectly and went to the Contact page. But when executing
   using the HTTPS environment, the page instead went to the Select
   Company page (the one in Step 2).

I haven't been able to sleep for a few nights due to this problem. So any help guys is appreciated. :-)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: We need to see some code to see what you are doing. Also the versions of everything you are using.

Comment: hi Arran. basically, the code are just: driver.Url = "testsite.com/page.aspx"; or driver.Navigate().GoToUrl = "testsite.com/page.aspx"; both codes above are working perfectly for an HTTP site, but is redirecting improperly for an HTTPS site. :-( i am running the scripts using the latest drivers for IE and Firefox

Comment: Please post the *exact* code you are using. Also whether or not this occurs with a public HTTPS site, such as a banking site or the HTTPS version of Facebook.